# Shuffle an array with interval return TypeError is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to shuffle a list every 10 seconds. This list is the datasource of a mat-table

```
  list = [
    { position: 1, name: 'player1' },
    { position: 2, name: 'player2' },
    { position: 3, name: 'player3' },
    { position: 4, name: 'player4' },
    { position: 5, name: 'player5' },
    { position: 6, name: 'player6' },
    { position: 7, name: 'player7' },
    { position: 8, name: 'player8' },
    { position: 9, name: 'player9' },
  ];

  dataSource = this.list;
```

I have a function that shuffles an array. ref: [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array)

```
shuffleArray(array):[] {
    let currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

    // While there remain elements to shuffle...
    while (0 !== currentIndex) {

      // Pick a remaining element...
      randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
      currentIndex -= 1;

      // And swap it with the current element.
      temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
      array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
      array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }

    return array;
  }
```

When I just call it onInit() works fine, and shuffles the list once

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.shuffleDatasource();
  }

  shuffleDatasource(): void {
    this.dataSource = this.shuffleArray(this.list);
  }
```

When I call it on interval like this,

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.shuffleDatasource();
    setInterval(this.shuffleDatasource, 10000);
  }
```

I get the error: `ERROR TypeError: this.shuffleArray is not a function`

Do you have any ideas of fixing this issue?

Comment: You have passed a function reference to `setInterval`. The function will be called without any particular `this` binding. See the reference Q&A in the closure reason box. One solution for that problem: `setInterval(() => this.shuffleDatasource(), 10000);`. Didn't check if your code has any other issues. NB: don't repeat the tag-informations in the title.

Comment: I cannot call the shuffleDataSource without this binding. I have to call the instance member. With your solution the error disappears but the list shuffles only in the beginning. I don't know why my question is closed and associated with the question about what is the this keyword. I think it's irrelevant, here.

Comment: Your question was *"I get the error: ERROR TypeError: this.shuffleArray is not a function. Do you have any ideas of fixing this issue?"*. The answer is Yes, check out the duplicate reference. You are now coming with another issue, which was not the subject of your question.

Comment: The title of the question is "shuffle an array with interval returns...". Not the this keyword. I just copied and pasted the error in the end. This was my issue from the start and I didn't came with a new one. You should read the post before flag it as duplicate. Of course I use this in Angular; how else sould I call a method onInit?

Comment: I will not continue the discussion. I quoted your question in my previous comment. I did read your whole post diligently. We are volunteers trying to help. The linked dupe reference will help you with the question I quoted in my previous comment. It was at that moment the only phrase with a question mark (and that is good, because there should be only one question). You clearly asked any ideas of fixing ***this issue***, referring to the error message.

Comment: @v_char *"With your solution the error disappears but the list shuffles only in the beginning."* How do you know it is shuffled only once? The code you are currently providing does not produce any output. Maybe it is shuffled every 10 seconds, but you render it only the first time. Try adding a `console.log(this.dataSource)` after shuffling in `shuffleDatasource` to validate that it is indeed (not) shuffling every 10 seconds.

Comment: @3limin4t0r very good point. It, indeed, shuffles, but it's not rendered in the view. I have to find a way out of re-render the view in every interval. Thanks for commenting

Comment: I'm not familiar with Angular, but my guess is that it does not re-render because `shuffleArray` is an in-place algorithm and shuffles the array argument passed in. For chaining convenience the argument is also returned (similar to the standard array `sort` method). Because it is in-place `dataSource` will hold the same object reference after being shuffled, because of this Angular might assume that there where no changes. Try and see if creating a new array for each shuffle solves the problem. `this.shuffleArray(Array.from(this.list))` this also prevents `this.list` from being shuffled.

Comment: @3limin4t0r you were completely right! Array.from works like a charm :)